# OrderCloud.io API XP Size Limit

Tags: angularjs, json, database, ordercloud

I'm part of a team developing an ecommerce site through the ordercloud.io API. I'm trying to figure out how much information I can store in a JSON object's xp key. The project I'm working on requires some pretty custom configuration and data storage, and I want to make sure the process I come up with will scale well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XP value in OrderCloud is limited by a maximum string size of 8000 characters. However, you really shouldn't try to reach this value because it may drain on the performance of your API requests (that's a lot of data to send over the wire, especially if you are getting a list of objects).

Make sure you review existing features to see if there is a way to accomplish what you are trying to store/behavior you are trying to create. Or consider storing in a separate location (your own db or an integration that helps fulfill the feature).